# RuntimeError: Event loop is closed in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, environment-variables, discord.py

I'm having a problem with running my bot.
The code:

```
import discord
import asyncpg
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv('.env')

TOKEN = os.environ.get('BOT_TOKEN')

intents = discord.Intents(messages = True, guilds = True, reactions = True, members = True, presences = True)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ['d!', 'D!'], case_insensitive = True, intents = intents)

client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity = discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.watching, 
                                                                name = 'a movie.'))
    print('Bot is ready!')

extensions = ['cogs.AdminCommands', 'cogs.MiscCommands', 'cogs.FunCommands', 'cogs.HelpCommands']
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for ext in extensions:
        client.load_extension(ext)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Jake\Documents\GitHub\tourney-bot\dominant_bot.py", line 51, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000242380BCF70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000242380BCF70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000242380BCF70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000242380BCF70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000242380BCF70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000242380BCF70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000242380BCF70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000242380BCF70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000242380BCF70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000242380BCF70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

The error seems to be with environment variables because when I run the code by using the actual token instead of using TOKEN in `client.run()`, it works perfectly.

I have also tried using `os.getenv()` instead of `os.environ.get` and the same problem still occurs.

There are also no issues with the **.env** file, as it is in the same directory as the **bot.py** file and all the variables are correct.

Comment: Please post the whole traceback, not just a random, useless line.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński edited.

Comment: It says that the token is `None`. Check and see if the token is correct and is actually there.